# Issue in NuoDB in date_to_str with a pattern with miliseconds

Tags: date, casting, nuodb

I want to make in NuoDB the cast from str to date with a 6 milliseconds precision. The problem is that sometimes it rounds it to 3 milliseconds. It seems that the problem is when the fourth millisecond is 5 or bigger, is there any way that it doesn't do that? I need always 6 milliseconds.

SQL> select DATE_FROM_STR('09-06-2017 10:01:36.111499', 'MM-dd-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS') from dual;

### date_from_str

2016-12-26 10:01:36.111499

SQL> select DATE_FROM_STR('09-06-2017 10:01:36.111599', 'MM-dd-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS') from dual;

### date_from_str

2016-12-26 10:01:36.112

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

You have stumbled upon a known issue and we've already turned around a fix for it!  Our next NuoDB GA will include this fix and will be available shortly.